# Python Mailgun API Not Sending Email

Tags: python, api, email, mailgun

When running the program the email does not appear in my mailbox, I do not get any errors.

```
import requests
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox26ec5a4187a942f6a834bb53d77d2b31.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@sandbox26ec5a4187a942f6a834bb53d77d2b31.mailgun.org>",
            "to": ["MY_EMAIL", "MY_SECOND_EMAIL"],
            "subject": "Hello",
            "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

Comment: What is the issue with the email? Also, I'm 99% sure that the Api Key is correct. Thanks!

Comment: The things in your `to` list are not email addresses.

Comment: did you check result from `post()`? `response = requests.post(...)` and `print( response.text )` - maybe it sends some information in response.  OR maybe you get mail in `Spam`

Answer (score 0):

If this is all your code, you might miss send_simple_message() after the definition. It seems you built definition without calling it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).